# How to increase google cloud VM SSH window buffer size, using command line

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Have a Linux VM instance on GCP Compute Engine.  I can SSH connect to it and load my files and run a python file which outputs to the console, but the window will start deleting the top lines when it gets to like 40 lines.  Is there a way to increase the limit or buffer limit?

`gcloud compute update ...`

Comment: How about redirecting the stdout and stderr to files that you can later load and visualise?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you might be running your commands on Cloud Shell, Putty or similar tools. Considering the different scenarios I am providing four solutions that may help you resolve the issue.

1. By enabling accessibility features
   In order to provide a more streamlined screen reader experience, the gcloud command-line tool comes with an accessibility/screen_reader property.
   To enable these accessibility features, you can run this command:

$ gcloud config set accessibility/screen_reader true

Refining gcloud CLI output
For list commands, you can further refine your output by using the --limit flag to set a maximum number of resources to list. You can also use the --page-size flag to define the number of resources per page if the service lists output in pages. To sort, use the --sort-by flag with the relevant field to sort.
To structure and produce more meaningful output, you can use the format, filter and projection flags to fine-tune your output.
If you'd like to define just the format of your output, use the --format flag to produce a tabulated or flattened version of your output (for interactive display) or a machine-readable version of the output (json, csv, yaml, value).
To format a list of keys that select resource data values, use projections.
To further refine your output to a criteria you'd like to define, use the --filter flag.
You can refer to these related public documentations:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/enabling-accessibility-features
https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-the-cloud-shell-terminal

2. By increasing size in tmux

To create a pane with a different value you will need to set the appropriate history-limit option before creating the pane. The history limit is a pane attribute that is fixed at the time of pane creation and cannot be changed for existing panes.

To establish a different default, you can add a similar line in your .tmux.conf file:

```
set-option -g history-limit 3000
```

For a new pane (or the initial pane in a new window) in an existing session, you can set that session’s history-limit. You can use a command like this (from a shell):
tmux set-option history-limit 5000 ; new-window

3. By buffering in standard streams

Default Buffering modes:
stdin is buffered (line buffering doesn't affect stdin)
stdout is buffered (line buffered if connected to a terminal)
stderr is unbuffered
Default Buffer sizes:
Buffer size only directly affects buffered mode
The default size like the kernel is based on the page size (4096 bytes on my system)
if stdin/stdout are connected to a terminal then default size = 1024; else size = 4096
You can check the following documentation to control the buffering.
http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/

4. By increasing buffer size in Putty

Load the session, then go to the Window category in the left pane and change Lines of scrollback as per your requirement. Go back to the Session category and save it.
[http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback](http://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-scrollback)